# Checking if any competitors have a non-empty name

Tags: javascript, lodash.js

Take this:

```
has_competitors:function(){
  var c = false;
  _.each(this.competitors, function(obj, index){ // lodash here
    if(obj.name && obj.name.trim() !== ''){
      c = true;
      return false; // to break the loop
    }
  });
  return c;
}
```

I don't like the form of this, but till now I didn't find a more concise way. Could you suggest a better way? :) I mean, less lines.

Comment: What does this function do? Please tell us, and make that the title of the question — see [ask]. Also tell us what `_` is — use the [tag:lodash.js] or [tag:underscore.js] tag as appropriate.

Comment: There were already enough informations to have 2 answers and one accepted, so I don't really see the point. Anyway, added the informations you're asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library.

You may use [_.some](https://lodash.com/docs/#some) function.

> Checks if predicate returns truthy for any element of collection. Iteration is stopped once predicate returns truthy. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).

```
has_competitors: function(){
    return _.some(this.competitors, function(obj){
        return obj.name && obj.name.trim() !== '';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4):

- Since ES5 (which all browsers support nowadays) is [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). It works in the same way as Lodash's/Underscore's `_.some()` but without the library.
- If you target ES6, you can further trim your code using [shorthand object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- Your `object.trim()` can blow up if `object.name` is truthy but not a string. Do a `typeof obj.name === 'string'` instead of a truthy check. If it is always guaranteed to be a string, the truthy check is redundant since a trimmed empty string will always be empty.

So your code could be as simple as:

```
has_competitors(){
  return this.competitors.some(obj => obj.name.trim() !== '') 
}
```

Comment: Good suggestions. Anyway in my case competitors is a collection (obj) not an array, so I'll go for lodash.